# How to get the selected value of dropdownlist inside a table cell using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML element like this:

```
<td>
    <select>
        <option value="Polygon 47">Polygon 47</option>
        <option value="Polygon 49">Polygon 49</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

How can I access the currently selected value with JavaScript?

Comment: when do you want to access? on option change or on button click?

Comment: When I call a different function (is called when I hit the a button), I want to select the currently set value.

Comment: There is a lot of work for this without having id for the dropdown. Find one parent element with `id` property, and then find the containing elements by accessing `childNodes` property of that element in `javascript`. You need to do this until you get the required element. **OR** use `jquery` which would be lot easier that javascript in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `getElementsByTagName`.

```
        var e = cell.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        var myValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
<select id="shape">
<option value="Polygon 47">Polygon 47</option>
<option value="Polygon 49">Polygon 49</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#shape').change(function(){
    var shapeId = document.getElementById("shape");
    var shapeChosen = shapeId.options[shapeId.selectedIndex].value;
    //Now use 'shapeChosen' wherever you want. 'shapeChosen' will give you the selected item.
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The question is about doing it in JS and NOT jQuery!

Comment: Using jQuery is a better option!

Comment: One would not simply have a website with just a select box!

Comment: it doesn't mean you can't have a site with no jQuery!

Comment: That's why is said jQuery is a 'better' option. I did not say the 'only' option.

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="test">
<option value="Polygon 47">Polygon 47</option>
<option value="Polygon 49">Polygon 49</option>
</select>

$("#test").change(function() {alert($("#test option:selected").val())})
```

Comment: Well, if we're going to get downvoted for trying to help, I'll move on then. Best of luck with finding a solution.